# How to display an image only inside of container div with a body background?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been experimenting with some basic code for image movement animation, taking advantage of the `absolute` position property and changing the `left` value on a `setInterval` upon page load.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Moving out of border</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='container'>
      <img class='movingimage' src='https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/716412?s=460&v=4'>
    </div>
    <!--<div id='container' style='background: #000000;'>-->
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
body {
  background: url('http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/images/gamesbackground2.png') no-repeat;
  font-size: 0px;
}

#container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #6495ed;
}

.movingimage {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 130px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

And here is the Javascript:

```
$(function() {  
  setInterval(function() {
    var currLeft = $('.movingimage').position().left;
    currLeft += 3;
    if (currLeft < 510) {
      $('.movingimage').css({left: currLeft + 'px'});
    }    
  }, 20);  
});
```

Alternatively, you can see my code [here](https://codepen.io/gfcf14/pen/ZrmwrE)

So basically, the page I'm doing this on has a background image, where a container with a background color has an image that moves to the right. Once the image completely goes over the boundaries of the container, it should stop.

What I would like to do is display the image only while it is inside the container. This means, if half of the image goes over the border, then only the half that remains inside would be displayed.

I tried experimenting with a different container (the commented-out div) next to the one that contains the image act as a cover once the image steps out of  bounds, and while that does the trick I would like to achieve the same thing without it. Is there any way to accomplish this?

As always, thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Got it. I added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to the `#container` selector in your CSS file as below:

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Since your `img` tag is a child of your `#container`, it will simply get clipped by the CSS if it goes outside of the `#container`'s bounds.

Comment: That was simple. Thank you so much!